# mod_rewrite params inversion

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I create the mod_rewrite rule so I can convert the following URLs:

**From:**
domain/something/param/action
ex:domain/cities/Chicago/view

**to:** 
domain/something/action.php?param1=param
ex: domain/cities/view.php?city=Chicago

Changing to cities/view/Chicago cannot be an alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: richsage, thank you very much.

It worked perfectly fine! I didn't know I could use the file name also as a parameter.

best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this will work (don't have access to a server at present to check I'm afraid):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /$1/$3.php?city=$2
```

Any use?  This assumes your domain is the root of the server eg http://www.example.com/cities/Chicago/view